# Identification of Pin1 on LAN8720A 24SQFN package

Tags: identification, pinout, lan8720

can anybody help me identify which is pin 1 please?  - which corner and side is pin 1?

I find the data sheet and the actual picture confusing between the [Datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I64h.png)

and the device [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the white dot just below the letter B.

If you scroll on the next page of datasheet where you copied that picture, there is a picture with chips packed in tape and it also shows the alignment of pin 1 in respect to the SMSC logo